# ASP.NET Webforms - "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-3.5

I'm getting the following error when I submit html in a textarea "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client." How do I disable this type of security validation to just one field and not the entire page/website. What I do NOT want to do is set validateRequest to false for an entire page/website.

EDIT:
I need a solution for .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Have you thought of just encoding/decoding that value?

Comment: Yes but what's the best way of implementing this solution? Should I just overwrite the value of the control with its HTML encoded value and then decode it on PageLoad? I'm using Telerik's RadEditor (WYSIWYG) control and I'm not sure if I will inadvertently break something by fiddling with its values.

Comment: No idea, but if you're using telerik, there should be some magical setting that allows it. I would suggest contacting telerik or searching their documentation for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 4.5 you can use the [`ValidateRequestMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.validaterequestmode.aspx) property to exclude fields from Request Validation.

However in .NET 4 and Lower this cannot be done, and you must either validate the **entire** request or not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need a solution for .NET 3.5.